# Identify Blank CDs an DVDs

Tags: dvd, compact-disc

I have Two identical spindles full of blank disks (light scribe CD-R en DVD-R). How do I figure out what spindle has DVDs and which has CDs. It is light scribe disc so they are have no writing on.

Comment: Don't they say "DVD" or "CD" on the tops of the disks?

Comment: I assume you are referring to CD-Rs and DVD-Rs. Are you sure they all look _exactly_ the same? They almost _always_ look a little bit different. In most cases, the bottom of the DVD-Rs look a bit blue or purple, while the back of the CD-Rs a a bit more green. I don't know the reason for this, but it almost always seems to be the case.

Comment: Some blank CDs/DVDs are just a plain color on the top.  @Izam makes a good point, all blank DVDs I've seen are purple on the bottom.

Comment: I looked at the disks and it looks like DVD are blue and CD are green. I suspect it is due to the different optical characteristics of the media.

Answer (score 0):

I found a windows application ([DVD Identifier](http://dvd.identifier.cdfreaks.com/)) that gives you information on the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Without reference to any labelling the media may have, you can tell CD-R and DVD-R apart by the appearance of the bottom surface. Both will show an iridescent "rainbow" effect in addition to a sort of overall "base" color. CD-R will have a generally green or green/gold hue and DVD-R will have a distinct purplish hue. Holding a sample of each side by side, the difference should be obvious.